# Down load data from HTTPS in R

Tags: r, https, download

I have a problem with downloading data from HTTPS in R, I try using curl, but it doesn't work.

```
URL <- "https://github.com/Bitakhparsa/Capstone/blob/0850c8f65f74c58e45f6cdb2fc6d966e4c160a78/Plant_1_Generation_Data.csv"

options('download.file.method'='curl')
download.file(URL, destfile = "./data.csv", method="auto")
```

I downloaded the CSV file with that code, but the format was changed when I checked the data. So it didn't download correctly.
Would you please someone help me?

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: The `fread()` function from data.table is good for downloading data files, just with the url string straight into it: `fread("https://git....`

Answer (score 5):

I think you might actually have the URL wrong. I think you want:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bitakhparsa/Capstone/0850c8f65f74c58e45f6cdb2fc6d966e4c160a78/Plant_1_Generation_Data.csv

Then you can download the file directly using `library(RCurl)` rather than creating a variable with the URL

```
library(RCurl)
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bitakhparsa/Capstone/0850c8f65f74c58e45f6cdb2fc6d966e4c160a78/Plant_1_Generation_Data.csv",destfile="./data.csv",method="libcurl")
```

You can also just load the file directly into R from the site using the following

```
URL <- "https://github.com/Bitakhparsa/Capstone/blob/0850c8f65f74c58e45f6cdb2fc6d966e4c160a78/Plant_1_Generation_Data.csv"
out <- read.csv(textConnection(URL))
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if the solution worked for you

Answer (score 4):

You can use the 'raw.githubusercontent.com' link, i.e. in the browser, when you go to "https://github.com/Bitakhparsa/Capstone/blob/0850c8f65f74c58e45f6cdb2fc6d966e4c160a78/Plant_1_Generation_Data.csv" you can click on the link "View raw" (it's above "Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.") and this takes you to the actual data. You also have some minor typos.

This worked as expected for me:

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bitakhparsa/Capstone/0850c8f65f74c58e45f6cdb2fc6d966e4c160a78/Plant_1_Generation_Data.csv"
download.file(url, destfile = "./data.csv", method="auto")
df <- read.csv("~/Desktop/data.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new at data science, and I was confused.